# how to bind data on MVC View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I created one Partial View with model class SchoolViewModel. I am able to listing product on table but I cannot understand How to bind Product list on Html div tag.

this is my @model IEnumerable Model class

I want output like this
[image: output image]

Here is my View source code

```
        <div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">

                <div class="item active"> 

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="col-item">
                                <div class="photo">
                                    <img src="~/image/img/manav-rachna.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="info">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="price col-md-12" style="margin-top:-50px">
                                            <img src="~/image/l.jpg" class="pull-left img-thumbnail">
                                            <h5 style="color:#FFFFFF">
                                                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                <b>Manav Rachna International School</b><span class="price-text-color">  [ Faridabad ]</span>
                                            </h5>

                                            <a href="#" class="pull-right" style="color:#EAEA00"><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i></a>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li style="float:left;padding:5px"><i class="fa fa-inr"></i>1.90 L/Yr</li>
                                        <li style="float:left;padding:5px"><a href="#">|</a></li>
                                        <li style="float:left;padding:5px"><i class="fa fa-inr"></i>4.1/5 Review</li>



                                    </ul>
                                    <div class="separator clear-left">
                                        <p class="btn-add">
                                            <i class="fa fa-headphones"></i><a href="#" class="hidden-sm">Enquiry</a>
                                        </p>
                                        <p class="btn-details">
                                            <i class="fa fa-list"></i><a href="#" class="hidden-sm">View Details</a>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearfix">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>  





                    </div>    
                </div>    

                <div class="item"><div class="row">
                                      <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                          <div class="col-item">
                                              <div class="photo">
                                                  <img src="~/image/img/manav-rachna.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="info">
                                                  <div class="row">
                                                      <div class="price col-md-12" style="margin-top:-50px">
                                                          <img src="~/image/l.jpg" class="pull-left img-thumbnail">
                                                          <h5 style="color:#FFFFFF">
                                                              &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                              <b>Manav Rachna International School</b><span class="price-text-color">  [ Faridabad ]</span>
                                                          </h5>

                                                          <a href="#" class="pull-right" style="color:#EAEA00"><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i></a>
                                                      </div>

                                                  </div>
                                                  <ul>
                                                      <li style="float:left;padding:5px"><i class="fa fa-inr"></i>1.90 L/Yr</li>
                                                      <li style="float:left;padding:5px"><a href="#">|</a></li>
                                                      <li style="float:left;padding:5px"><i class="fa fa-inr"></i>4.1/5 Review</li>



                                                  </ul>
                                                  <div class="separator clear-left">
                                                      <p class="btn-add">
                                                          <i class="fa fa-headphones"></i><a href="#" class="hidden-sm">Enquiry</a>
                                                      </p>
                                                      <p class="btn-details">
                                                          <i class="fa fa-list"></i><a href="#" class="hidden-sm">View Details</a>
                                                      </p>
                                                  </div>
                                                  <div class="clearfix">
                                                  </div>
                                              </div>
                                          </div>
                                      </div>


                    </div> </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your partial view you will need something like:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyWebApplication.MyModel>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Col1
        </th>
        <th>
            Col2
        </th>
    </tr>

   <tbody>    
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.PropertyOne)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @HtmlDisplayFor(model => item.PropertyTwo)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have used a table and `DisplayFor` as it is the most common scenario for displaying a IEnumerable of models, you can obviously put whatever HTML you like in your page, it doesn't have to be a table for it to work.

See this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee308450(v=vs.98).aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the model data in the view after that it is very simple, you just need to iterate through your list of data and render the div or block. like this

```
<ul>

@foreach(var item in Model)
{
      <li>item.Name</li>
}

</ul>
```

this is just example, you can add anything within the foreach loop, in your case it must be your div where you are showing list of top schools

Comment: sir i am able to bind on table ,but here the main problem is that ,i have one main div in main div there is one item div ,on item div i have to list only 4 product list ,and then again repeat Item div